# GHC can not find installed module

Tags: haskell, package, ghc

My haskell installation can not find bytestring module installed by operating system

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :m +Data.ByteString.Lazy

<no location info>:
Could not find module `Data.ByteString.Lazy'
It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

But I have installed this module using yum:

```
$ rpm -ql ghc-bytestring
/usr/lib64/ghc-7.6.3/bytestring-0.10.0.2
/usr/lib64/ghc-7.6.3/bytestring-0.10.0.2/libHSbytestring-0.10.0.2-ghc7.6.3.so
/usr/share/doc/ghc-bytestring
/usr/share/doc/ghc-bytestring/LICENSE
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Situation here is similiar to C++ you have libraries used during dynamic linking stage and header used for compilation. In Fedora packages like ghc-bytestring are only libraries without headers. To install headers I had to install ghc-bytestring-devel package.

An example on Fedora 24:

```
server.hs:7:8:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Text’
    Perhaps you meant Data.Set (from containers-0.5.5.1)
    Locations searched:
      Data/Text.hs
      Data/Text.lhs
```

So change to user `root`, then:

What packages are there?

```
# dnf search ghc|grep text

ghc-text.x86_64 : An efficient packed Unicode text type
ghc-boxes.x86_64 : 2D text pretty-printing library
ghc-pango.x86_64 : Binding to the Pango text rendering engine
ghc-css-text.x86_64 : CSS parser and renderer
ghc-hgettext.x86_64 : Haskell binding to libintl
ghc-attoparsec.x86_64 : Fast combinator parsing for bytestrings and text
ghc-text-devel.x86_64 : Haskell text library development files
ghc-blaze-textual.x86_64 : Fast rendering of common datatypes
ghc-css-text-devel.x86_64 : Haskell css-text library development files
ghc-hgettext-devel.x86_64 : Haskell hgettext library development files
ghc-blaze-textual-devel.x86_64 : Haskell blaze-textual library development files
```

So what's installed?

```
# rpm --query ghc-text
ghc-text-1.1.1.3-3.fc24.x86_64

# rpm --query ghc-text-devel
package ghc-text-devel is not installed
```

So let's install the devel package.

```
# dnf install ghc-text-devel
Installed:
  ghc-text-devel.x86_64 1.1.1.3-3.fc24
```

...and compilation succeeds after that.

Comment: Nice, that's exactly it. I would not have found out, as "devel"  I added an example for "Data.Text". It's a bit surprising as I was thinking of Haskell as being more like Java which rarely needs `devel` packages when you write new code than C++.

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening, you should be able to figure out more via `ghc-pkg list`. This could happen, for example, if the binary package provided by your software repository was broken; `ghc-pkg list` would report that. In general, either GHC is not looking for packages in `/usr/lib64/ghc-7.6.3/` or else that directory has a `package.cache` which was not updated to reflect the new package.

One thing that could cause GHC to look in the wrong place is if there are multiple GHCs on the machine: for example if `which ghc` reveals `/usr/local/bin/ghc` then you probably compiled GHC from source at some point and its packages are occupying some `/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.6.3/package.conf.d/` folder, while your repository has installed `/usr/bin/ghc` which is looking in the folder you want.

Anyway, fixes: if the `package.cache` file exists and has a valid entry for the file, then you can run `ghc -package-conf /path/to/package.cache ...` to add those packages to your executable. If you have further problems, `ghc -v ...` is a great resource for debugging "which version of that package is being used here?" types of problems.

If the `package.cache` file does not exist then you've got a bigger problem, and probably the easiest way to move forward is to look for a directory under `/home` which appears on `ghc-pkg list`. Install the required package to that directory and GHC should pick up on it even though it doesn't understand these bigger contexts. You could also start working with a `cabal` sandbox of local packages to your project.